# Mixing chromeOptions.args cli and protractor.conf.js

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

Currently we have a "standard" protractor.conf.js file in place. It has a chrome specific section which looks something like this:

```
 capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                '--no-sandbox', '--window-size=1280,1480', '--window-position=800,0'
            ],
            prefs: {
                intl: {accept_languages: defaults.LANGUAGE},
            },
        },
}
```

When we run the tests locally, everything is fine.
On our CI Infrastructure we add via CLI call the headless option:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --capabilities.chromeOptions.args='headless'
```

First everything looked fine. The tests were running with headless chrome. But we recognized that the `--window-size=1280,1480` specified in the config file was not used. We removed the `--capabilities` from the cli call and added the `headless` option directly into the protractor.conf.js.

Everything was now also working fine on the CI Infrastructure. This means the `--window-size` specified in the config was recognized and used.

Further tests showed, that if we want to use the CLI arguments, we would need to also add the `window-size` to the CLI call, to get it working as it should.

Now the question itself:

Why is this like that ? Shouldn't it be possible to add **additional** chromeOptions.args via CLI call ? Are the chromeOptions.args from the config no longer respected when passing some chromeOptions.args via CLI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, The CLI values will overwrite the value in conf.js.

Below is the code snippet from [launcher.ts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/launcher.ts#L98)

```
let initFn = function(configFile: string, additionalConfig: Config) {
  let configParser = new ConfigParser();
  if (configFile) { // this is the protractor conf.js
    configParser.addFileConfig(configFile);
  }
  if (additionalConfig) { // this is all cli arguments
    configParser.addConfig(additionalConfig);
  }
```

Below is the `addConfig` from [configParser.ts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/configParser.ts#L167)

```
  public addConfig(argv: any): ConfigParser {
    this.addConfig_(argv, process.cwd());
    return this;
  }

  private addConfig_(additionalConfig: any, relativeTo: string): void {
    // All filepaths should be kept relative to the current config location.
    // This will not affect absolute paths.
    ['seleniumServerJar', 'chromeDriver', 'firefoxPath', 'frameworkPath', 'geckoDriver',
     'onPrepare']
        .forEach((name: string) => {
          if (additionalConfig[name] && typeof additionalConfig[name] === 'string') {
            additionalConfig[name] = path.resolve(relativeTo, additionalConfig[name]);
          }
        });

    merge_(this.config_, additionalConfig);
  }


let merge_ = function(into: any, from: any): any {
  for (let key in from) {
    if (into[key] instanceof Object && !(into[key] instanceof Array) &&
        !(into[key] instanceof Function)) {
      merge_(into[key], from[key]);
    } else {
      into[key] = from[key];
    }
  }
  return into;
};
```

Because `capabilities.chromeOptions.args` is Array, thus the args value in conf.js will be overwrite by value from cli in `merge_` function: `into[key] = from[key];`

Therefor, you have to specify all chromeOptions.args from cli by using multiple `--capabilities.chromeOptions.args=xxx` in cli, rather than 
partial.

```
protractor conf.js \
--capabilities.chromeOptions.args='headless' \
--capabilities.chromeOptions.args='--no-sandbox' \
--capabilities.chromeOptions.args='--window-size=1280,1480'
```

Comment: As overwritten we had understood it means, if we provide an argument on cli it will &quot;overwrite&quot; the value of this property from the config if set. If not it will be added. But as you prove, this is not the case. The whole array is overwritten.